Как открыть excel файл в питоне?
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Admin\excel import1.py")
sheet_name = 1

Не может найти файл.
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/налитик данных/Т программы/import os.py"
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\налитик данных\\Т программы\\import 
os.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Admin> 


В чем сложность загуглить ошибку? У вас pyton не может найти файл 'c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\налитик данных\Т программы\import
os.py', Скорее всего проблема в русских символах, подобные вопросы на форумах появлялись уже тысячу раз, так неужели не найти ни одного?

pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Admin\excelnew.xls")

Скопировал файл excelnew в основную директорию. Теперь не может установить pandas.

PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "c:/Users/Admin/excel import1.py"
File "c:\Users\Admin\excel import1.py", line 1
pip install pandas
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\Admin>

Я только начинаю с питоном работать. Вам может и все просто, мне - нет.

Анаконду удалил. Работаю через visual studio

Возможно, раз для Вас загуглить - такая огромная проблема, то может быть, программирование - это не для вас?

Если ничего не можете подсказать, лучше займитесь другим делом

А просто нужно было подсказать, что все эти модули подгружаются ( их не было в питоне)  и разархивируются из командной строки! Cmd. А не задирать нос.  Все заработало!

А просто нужно было подсказать, что все эти модули подгружаются ( их не было в питоне)  и разархивируются из командной строки! Cmd.  Все заработало!
